# Password reset email marked as spam by Gmail

Tags: support, email

I requested a password reset and today I noticed the email ended up in my spam folder. The "stackoverflow.email" domain did look suspicious to me as well, but maybe there's something you can do to avoid being flagged as spam.

[image: Screenshot of email]

Comment: Thanks for the report. We've heard this from others and are looking into it. For the time being, the solution is to add the email address to your address book... though that's one odd email address... the stackoverflow.email is normal but the numbers seems odd. Sorry for any confusion. Also, do you want your email posted publicly? If you edit the image to remove it, we can clear the history.

Comment: It's fine, it's already posted in many other places and it's not exactly hard to guess.